# ionic2 camera capture + transmission to express 4.0 server

Tags: node.js, typescript, angular, ionic2, multer

After capturing image via ionic2 native camera module:

```
public fileToSend: File;

Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
 fileToSend = imageData;
}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});
```

// function that is used to send the above captured (fileToSend) to server

```
 makeFileRequest(file: File) {

        return Observable.create(observer => {

            let formData: FormData = new FormData(),
            xhr: XMLHttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

            formData.append("file", file, file.name);

            xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        observer.next(JSON.parse(xhr.response));
                        observer.complete();
                    } else {
                        observer.error(xhr.response);
                    }
                }
            };
            let url = 'https://myserver/upload';
            xhr.open('POST', url, true);
            xhr.send(formData);
        });
    }
```

On the server we have multer setup as below:

```
var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null,  '../images');
  },
  filename: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.filename + '.jpeg');
  }
});

var upload = multer({storage: storage});

router.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
});
```

Instead of the file being stored as a file, it ends up in req.body. the console logs something like below:

```
{
  file: 'xyadfadfladflkadofa.......'
}
```

Why is the file not being sent as a file ?